# Architecture for a web app to add overlays to users' Youtube live stream video?

Tags: youtube-api, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to build a web app for users to easily add text (as open caption) and other assets in my app as overlays in real-time to their YouTube live stream video.

They will use their camera to record their video, and select from my app which text should be added to the video.

Then, the video will be sent to Youtube live through their API.

Here are my questions:

First of all, I was wondering if mixing video + subtitle and sending it to Youtube's rtmp url can be done from the client side, so it's simple and lightweight.

Second, should I encode the output being sent to Youtube? Can this be done from the browser too?
I'm only seeing a few node.js frameworks, and even they're not very mature (or is Webcodecs for this purpose?). Is a web app a poor choice for this task?

Lastly, if I do need a server to process the video, where should the encoding happen (from the user's machine, or in the server, or both?)? Is my server most likely going to be the bottleneck given YouTube's infrastructure, since video files are huge and my server is limited?

I am new to video streaming, so please excuse my lack of understanding of the subject. Also, if there's any good resource for my problem, please share them with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, I was wondering if mixing video + subtitle and sending it to Youtube's rtmp url can be done from the client side, so it's simple and lightweight.

You can do the video compositing and audio mixing and what not, but browsers don't support RTMP.  To get the data to an RTMP server, you need to send it to a server where it is proxied off to the final URL.

> They will use their camera to record their video, and select from my app which text should be added to the video.

Yeah, that's no problem at all.  Draw everything to a canvas every frame.

> Second, should I encode the output being sent to Youtube?

Yes, you must.  Check out the Media Recorder API.

> Lastly, if I do need a server to process the video, where should the encoding happen (from the user's machine, or in the server, or both?)?

The video has to be encoded client-side to get to the server in the first place.  The server can then hopefully just repackage with flv and send it along.  If the browser doesn't support H.264 in its Media Recorder API, then you'll have an intermediary codec like VP8, and you'll have to transcode server-side.

A few years ago, I wrote a tutorial on how to do all of these steps here:  https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example  Note that the tutorial is in the context of Facebook, but this should teach you the concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can I ask some more questions?

Comment: 1. Do you know the reason for browsers to not support RTMP? Is this the case for HLS and DASH too? (Clearly I'm not familiar with this)

Comment: 2. You said if the client can do the painting and encoding, my RTMP server would just repackage with flv and send it along to Youtube's rtmp url. Is this an expensive operation? It's a lot of data being sent over, so I'm worried the server cost would be huge, or my server will become the bottleneck.

Comment: RTMP was a protocol for Flash applications, and is essentially a dead technology.  It's still commonly used for source streams because, momentum.  HLS and DASH are just groups of files sent over HTTP, so the protocol is fine.  It's the packaging there that's the issue.  Muxing streams into FLV is very lightweight on your server CPU, but bandwidth consideration is still there... video streaming takes a great deal of bandwidth.  You should do the math on it though, because it's just one stream in/out... shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you!! For bandwidth problem, I should really think about it since the users' data redirected from my server to YouTube will be huge if the user base grows..

Comment: I have a working demo of what you are looking for at https://record.a.video.  The canvas is sent via socket to.a Node server, that converts to RTMP.  I then ingest at api.video (but YouTube works too).
Whatever you draw in the canvas is what is streamed.